# undefined method / for 15 ruby

Tags: ruby

I get an error `NoMeathodError undefined method / for 15` with this code:

```
tts = gets.chomp
2 * (tts / Math.sqrt(2)) + tts
```

where I set the `tts` value to `15`. If I change the first line to

```
tts = 15
```

The program successfully executes the equation. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `tts = gets.chomp.to_i`

Comment: The question should demonstrate minimal understanding of the topic by the asker.

Comment: btw why do you use: `2 * ( tts / Math.sqrt(2) ) + tts` and not `Math.sqrt(2) * tts + tts` ?

Answer (score 3):

So when you get a value from gets.chomp, it defaults it to a `string`. What you are getting back when you enter 15 into the terminal is the `string` "15" instead of the `integer` 15. In order to fix this, you can do the following:

`tts = gets.chomp.to_i`

Comment: To elicit the emotional reaction lol. It's upvote then =)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I think that this isn't true `What you are getting back when you enter 15 into the terminal is the string "15" instead of the integer 15.` If you enter in terminal `tts=15` , it will be a `Fixnum`.

Comment: Not my downvote but I can see a flaw.
What happens if the input is not an Integer-like string?
I would suggest that you have something like `tts = gets.chomp.to_i rescue 0`

Comment: @Vucko when you are obtaining a value through gets.chomp, it is a `string` not `Fixnum`.

Comment: @MitulP91 the OP doesn't use `chomp` in his second example - he just uses `tts = 15`. You should put in your answer that `chomp` returns a string.

Comment: I tried using gets.chomp.to_i and for my purposes at least, it worked perfectly first try.  Thank you for your help.